# I need to use a list Fragment and adapter to pass and update string data in the form of a to-do list

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am a fairly novice android programmer and I need some help in regards to the use of a List fragmnet.

To begin:

I currently have three main components in my simple To-do List application.

The first is a Main activity that impliments a custom method I made that simply updates the arraylist through the array Adapepter  I have made within it.

```
public class ToDoListActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnNewItemAddedListener{public void newItemAdded(String newItem)
{
    todoItems.add(newItem);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}



    public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    public ArrayList<String> todoItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //Inflate the root view
        setContentView(R.layout.to_do_list_activity);

        //Get references to the fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        ToDoListFragment toDoListFragment = (ToDoListFragment)
                fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ToDoListFragment);

        //Create the array list of to do items
        todoItems = new ArrayList<>();

        //Create the array adapter to bind the array to the listView
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);

        //Bind the array adapter to the listView
        toDoListFragment.setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_to_do_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //no inspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

I Also have an edit text fragment that handles the input of text that would be the To-do items. The newItem variable that is fed through the onNewItemListner() method is populated using my edit text fragment.

`public class EditTextFragment extends Fragment{
    //This variable stores a reference to the parent ToDoListActivity that implements
    //this interface.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //set the key listener on the edit text view on the UI. This handles the taps on the
    //Edit text box on the UI

    //inflate the view from the XML file
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_fragment, container, false);

    //Create the edit text variable where the reference to the UI XML file is
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);



    //Set a key listener on the edit text field
    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) ||
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    String newItem = myEditText.getText().toString();
                    ToDoListActivity onItemAddedListener = new ToDoListActivity();
                    onItemAddedListener.newItemAdded(newItem);
                    myEditText.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return view;
}






public void onAttach(ToDoListActivity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);



}
```

}`

Finally I have a List fragment.

```
public class ToDoListFragment extends ListFragment{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //Inflate the XML UI component for the
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_list_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
  }

public void onAttach(ToDoListActivity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

}

Now the problem I am running into is a null point exception. on the todoitems (arraylist) and the arrayAdapeter. They are for whatever reason not being instantiated. SO I can't pass any strings from my edit text field to them without crashing the app. I need to get them working and I would also like to use the list fragment to do so. Any help would be greatly appriciated. Any more information can be provided if needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your edit text fragment have no access to the ArrayList or ArrayAdapter. I can't really tell without seeing its code.

As I see you have your fragments embedded in activity's layout and accessing them by ID.
The fragments are useful if you want to have parts of your UI dynamically loaded/unloaded. If you are planning to have just ListView and edit text on the screen then probably you can do it without fragments. It would be much easier. Just put a regular ListView and EditText in your activity's layout.
Actually the ListFragment is a Fragment that hosts a ListView.

Comment: I can make it work without the fragments. But I wanted to try to do it using fragments such that later when I wanted to add more complex behavior I had the ground work already set.